# How to run iron-node using Grunt?

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, gruntjs, grunt-shell

I have installed `iron-node@3.0.7` and I am running `iron-node` normally is working.

But, when I run Grunt from a `Gruntfile.js`, `iron-node` is not able to run.

I am using the `grunt-shell` task.